# MobX Side effects like changing state are not allowed at this point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm not trying to modify state from render function. Actually, it's work if I remove `<ul>` tag. I don't know what to say. Please, StackOverflow gives me access to post this(sorry)

```
@observer
class LeftMenu extends Component {
  @observable rows = [];

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderRows(this.props.shareFiles);
  }

  renderRows = async (data, prevDir = "") => {
    const tempDir = prevDir;
    for (const dir of data) {
      const subDirectories = await API.browseFolder.getFiles({
        shareName: this.props.shareName,
        dirPath: prevDir === "" ? `${dir.name}` : `${tempDir}${dir.name}`
      });
      if (subDirectories.data.length) {
        prevDir += dir.name + "/";
        this.rows.push(
          <ul styleName="Main-row">
            {/* here's an error occurred */}
            <FolderRow onClick={this.onClick} label={dir.name} />
          </ul>
        );
        this.renderRows(subDirectories.data, prevDir);
      } else {
        this.rows.push(
          <FolderRow onClick={this.onClick} key={dir.name} label={dir.name} />
        );
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { shareName } = this.props;
    return (
      <div styleName="Container">
        <h3 styleName="Share-name">{shareName}</h3>
        <ul styleName="Main-row">{this.rows}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've been trying to resolve this all day :) Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you pushing React elements (JSX) to `rows` in `componentDidMount`? You could instead put the raw data in `rows` directly, and derive your JSX from that in the render method instead.

Comment: @Tholle cause my method for filling rows is async

Comment: You could fill the `rows` array in an asynchronous manner still, but with just the data. The component will re-render automatically if `rows` change if you use it in the render method instead.

Comment: @Tholle cause this method is also recursive. The main idea is calling the API method for getting a list of folders by folder name. I don't know how many folders do I have. So I'll call it 'til the end. So the idea of pushing JSX in the array the first thought pop up in my head)

Comment: Alright. Try to store the directories and subdirectories as regular data instead, and just derive the JSX from that data in the render method and it might work better.

Comment: @Tholle hm I think I got you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Tholle I did like you said and it's work fine. Yay. Thank a lot)